# .sh No such file or directory, file does exist

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix, shebang

The file exists, I see it in the relative path scripts/start_app.sh. I have the shebang correct at the top. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I've updated the packages by running:

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386`

./start_app.sh in terminal still yields: "No such file or directory"

I try to dos2unix the file. Doesn't work:

`$dos2unix start_app.sh`

`dos2unix: start_app.sh: No such file or directory`

`dos2unix: Skipping start_app.sh, not a regular file.`

Can someone help me with this?

(my .sh file)

```
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

[vscode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqQE7.png)

Comment: try `dos2unix scripts/start_app.sh`

Comment: still says dos2unix: scripts/start_app.sh: No such file or directory
dos2unix: Skipping scripts/start_app.sh, not a regular file.

Comment: I don't see in the code you posted, where you actually invoke `start_app.sh`, but since `dos2unix` says that this file does not exist in the working directory, you can be sure that the file really is not here, or at least that it is not a plain file (there could be a directory of this name). What makes you think that the file is there?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the file could be corrupted.

Try to run a few commands for troubleshooting:

```
$file start_app.sh
$ls -l start_app.sh
$stat start_app.sh
```

Please post the results.